# How to prevent eager evaluation?

Tags: f#

I'm trying some examples which use printfn a lot. I created a console app but all the functions print their output whether I call them or not. I believe that eager evaluation is behind my bug. Here is my code:

TextFormat.fs:

```
module TextFormat

    let printPi =
        let pi = System.Math.PI
        printfn "float: %f, exponent: %e, compact: %g" pi pi pi

        let petabyte = pown 2.0 50
        printfn "float: %f, exponent: %e, compact: %g" petabyte petabyte petabyte

    let printDecimal =
        let largeM = 123456789.123456789M
        printfn "float: %f, decimal: %M" largeM largeM

    let RunExamples () =
        do printDecimal
```

Program.fs:

```
open TextFormat

let exit () =
    printfn ""
    printfn "Press any key to exit"
    System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    RunExamples()

    exit()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

How can I force my program to print just the line I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not defining *functions*, but *values*.

When you write the following in F#:

```
let test =
  printfn "Hi"
```

... you are defining a value `test` that has a type `unit` (similar to `void` in C#) which is evaluated immediately and the result of the expression is stored in a value named `test`. The result of the expression is a `unit` value (which you cannot do much with), but it is a valid value.

On the other hand, when you write:

```
let test () =
  printfn "Hi"
```

... you are defining a function `unit -> unit` that is only evaluated when you call it (and then it prints "Hi" and returns a `unit` value as the result). To call the function, you'll also need to write `test ()` (using unit value as the argument) rather than just `test` (which refers to the function, but does not call it).

So, in your examples, you need to add an argument, for example:

```
let printPi () =
    let pi = System.Math.PI
    printfn "float: %f, exponent: %e, compact: %g" pi pi pi

    let petabyte = pown 2.0 50
    printfn "float: %f, exponent: %e, compact: %g" petabyte petabyte petabyte
```

Comment: Silly me, I should now this stuff. Thank you